# Confusion about distributing packages that contain OAuth2 credentials

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I'm currently writing a Node package that, when run by the user, will start a server and access data from their Google Drive. I am very much a beginner when it comes to authorization/authentication, so I'm very confused as to how this would be setup. From what I understand, OAuth2 is the way to do this, but the tutorials I've been reading on it require that both the public and secret keys be provided when authenticating with the Google API, and that the secret key is supposed to be kept private. If the secret key is supposed to be private, how can I just distribute it to everyone who downloads the package? Or is there maybe some other auth flow that would be more appropriate for this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is the [Implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) which allows you to use Oauth2.0 without the need to package your client secret in your app.

The link below details this flow type and even contains an example of how to access the Google Drive API.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent